# How to enable compression (gzip) for wesite pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed

I am getting pagespeed of my site 
http://ec2-54-64-172-159.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/SamePage_Website/
59/100. And it is referring to enable compression. I am new in this. May i know how to enable this.
http://ec2-54-64-172-159.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/phpinfo.php
some mods are installed. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+compression+on+amazon+aws

Answer (score 0):

You should tell this to your server provider technical team , they can do this easily.